# No mouse or keyboard input in Fallout New Vegas (aside from return and arrow keys)

Tags: pc, technical-issues, fallout-new-vegas

**Hardware/OS**

- CPU - Phenom II quad core
- GPU - R7950 HD
- RAM - 8GB
- SSD - 2x120GB RAID 0
- OS  - Windows 7

**Install Environment**

- Up-to-date windows
- Latest beta catalyst drivers
- Up-to-date game cache
- No Mods
- Other software runs fine (unlikely to be RAM)
- Mouse trails disabled

**Description**
I have New Vegas (installed through steam), it's been running fine since its install half a year ago.

I was playing a save yesterday, and after a couple of hours I encountered something that seemed like a memory problem (glitchy, shaky movement, clipping issues), which led to a CTD after several minutes.  I tried playing again today, and on passing the intro screens, I had no mouse cursor, and seemingly no keyboard input.

*Edit*: I was able to get into one of my saves using the arrow keys (should have thought of that).  I have no mouse input in game period, or keyboard input (aside from dpad and return)

*Edit 2* Going into the settings, there are no mouse or keyboard options period. Time for a complete reinstall of the game :( - the ESC key works for skipping the intro sequence, but no further.

**Steps Taken**

- Restarted PC, jiggled the cable
- I had an older catalyst driver, I updated to the latest beta (don't think this matters though)
- Verified the integrity of the game cache
- Deleted and allowed the game to re-create the .ini settings
- Searched for 3 or 4 pages and found no similar issues

Comment: Try doing system restore or file restore to an earlier date that the mouse was there, back up your save file before you do this.

Comment: @Wojtek'Charkz'Hordyniec I would NOT recommend this. He only has problems with his game, not the entire pc.

Comment: I gave him two options, file restore or system restore. It could very be some mod, or something he installed that is causing the problem or a dodgy graphics card update but not in his case. It has fixed problems before for my friends when I done it. System restore is a save procedure if you know what your doing and back up anything important.

Comment: After a certain amount of time, you will be able to accept your answer, which gives it a green checkmark and indicates that it resolves your question.  There is no need to edit your question to indicate that information.

Answer (score 2):

Welp.  My logitech controller driver changed in some way, or some kind of .ini thing happened, and new vegas decided to prefer it preferentially over everything.  I saw controller mappings in the settings menu, unplugged it, and got mouse/keyboard input back.  Plugging the controller in again cause the game to point out an option to disable 360 controllers, which I never paid attention to because I don't have a 360 controller (yeah yeah, 360 *mode*), and because this has never been an issue. I was about to reinstall when I noticed the button mappings in settings.

Thanks for your input VascovdEng and Wojtek.  Sorry if I wasted anyone's time, hopefully anyone else with this issue will see this.

Comment: Solution: Unplug your gamepad.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, upon googling your problem I came across this as the first link, this could be your answer, also go into your graphics options and disable 'Hardware Mouse Cursor" if the game has that option a lot of games do.

***From Steam support***

- **Please disable pointer trails for your mouse Start > Control Panel > Mouse > Pointer Options tab Uncheck the Display pointer trails box  If you are using Windows 7, make sure the Magnifier is disabled:
  Start > All Programs > Accessories > Ease of Access > Ease of Access
  Center Click on Make the computer easier to see Uncheck the Turn on
  Magnifier box and click OK**

Comment: I already have mouse trails off (in general, not as a step) - Nothing about my computer has changed *other* than the crash itself.  Thanks though.

Comment: Right, I know my friend had a problem with another steam game, and weirdly it just came back after a day or two, could be a steam glitch, maybe your best bet would be to contact them. After googling it. It seems there isn't anything that is a straight fix just theories.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look into it further, if this doesn't turn out to be a known issue I'll probably try a full re-install of the game(really not looking forward to that)

Comment: That could fix the problem, do you run any mods?

Comment: As I said in my OP, no mods.  I managed to get into a save, no keyboard or mouse input at all (details edited into OP)

Comment: Maybe uninstall your mouse and keyboard and install again, or look for updates for both. Computer>Manage>Device Manager> Right click on mouse look for updates. If that doesn't work you could also try updating your graphics card. As I don't know what your "catalyst" driver is I might of suggested something you already done.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but in my case, it turned out that the xbox controller (or any another controller) plugged into my PC leads to this strange cursor/enter/backspace problem. So check that you don´t have any another control devices connected at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Go into control settings and turn off 360 controller. Worked for me.